# How can I highlight duplicate rows in my sheet based on column value?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates, rows

I am trying to highlight duplicate rows in my sheet by checking for the same email address entered under the 'Email Address' column.

I have some code (below) that does this - it looks for duplicate rows based on repeated values under 'Email Address' and highlights them red. However, once I revisit the sheet, manually remove the duplicate row and rerun the script, the same row is highlighted again. Why is this happening and what can I do to ensure that when I update the sheet, the (now) unique row is not highlighted again?

```
function findDupes() {
  var CHECK_COLUMNS = [3];

  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var numRows = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  var numCols = sourceSheet.getLastColumn();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var newSheet = ss.insertSheet("FindDupes");


  for (var i = 0; i < CHECK_COLUMNS.length; i++) {
    var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1,CHECK_COLUMNS[i],numRows);
    var nextCol = newSheet.getLastColumn() + 1;
    sourceRange.copyTo(newSheet.getRange(1,nextCol,numRows));
  }


  var dupes = false;
  var data = newSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (i = 1; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
    for (j = i+1; j < data.length; j++) {
      if  (data[i].join() == data[j].join()) {
        dupes = true;
        sourceSheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,numCols).setBackground("crimson");
        sourceSheet.getRange(j+1,1,1,numCols).setBackground("crimson");
      }
    }
  }

  ss.deleteSheet(newSheet);

  if (dupes) {
    Browser.msgBox("Possible duplicate(s) found. Please check for repeat attendees.");
  } else {
    Browser.msgBox("No duplicates found.");
  }
};
```

I want to be able to run the script again once I have manually removed the rows and have it reflect the updated nature of the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Sorry, but there were so many things I couldn't understand why you were doing them that I find it easier just to show you how I'd do it.

```
function findAndHighlightDupesInColumn(col) {
  var col=col||3;//I think you wanted to check column 3
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();//gets all data
  var uA=[];//this is the array that hold all unique values
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++) {//assumes one header row
    if(uA.indexOf(vA[i][col-1])==-1) {//if it's unique then put it in uA
      uA.push(vA[i][col-1]);
    }else{//if it's not unique then set background color
      sh.getRange(i+1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).setBackground('crimson');
    }
  }
}
```

The following code will remove duplicates in column 3:

This method assumes that the first occurrence of any row is the row that you wish to keep.  All other duplicate rows are deleted.

```
function removeColumnDupes(col) {
  var col=col||3
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var uA=[];
  var d=0;
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(uA.indexOf(vA[i][col-1])==-1) {
      uA.push(vA[i][col-1]);
    }else{
      sh.deleteRow(i+1-d++);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! However, what I was trying to do earlier was to highlight both rows if there are duplicates, manually check and remove one, and then check again to see its a unique entry. With what you shared however, only one of the say, two duplicate rows are highlighted and I'm left to search for where the other one is. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this before the `for` loops. It will turn all the rows into white, and then the rest of your code will turn the duplicates red:

```
 sourceSheet.getRange(2,1,numRows,numCols).setBackground("white");
```

Also, you can add an onEdit() function to check for duplicates in real time, when you add or edit an email address:

```
function onEdit(e){

  if (e.range.getColumn() == 3){
    var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
    var numRows = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
    var numCols = sourceSheet.getLastColumn();

    var data = sourceSheet.getRange("C2:C"+numRows).getValues();
    var editedCell = e.value;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length;i++){ 
      if (editedCell == data[i] && (i + 2) != e.range.getRow()){
        sourceSheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(),1,1,numCols).setBackground("crimson");
        sourceSheet.getRange(i+2,1,1,numCols).setBackground("crimson");
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the issue with this code is that it only works on the first edit. Any subsequent edits are not captured.

Comment: I just tested the code again and it works well. The [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedite) function should work for every time you edit the Sheet. Can you write step by step the process you are following to write the values?